# How to add a content-type on a POST request with no body in OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: openapi

I am trying to create an OpenAPI 3.0 definition for an existing API. It has a POST operation and takes header values as the input. Request body is empty. However the backend API was coded very poorly and is expecting request header `Content-Type: application/json` even though the body is empty.

How do I achieve this in OpenAPI 3.0? Looks like `Content-Type` is not accepted as a valid header parameter in OAS 3.0.

Answer (score 16):

You can add the `requestBody` with the `application/json` media type but no `schema`.

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.2
...
paths:
  /something:
    post:
      parameters:
        ...
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json: {}
```

Comment: i think we have a better way :  requestBody:
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:      # Request body contents
          type: object

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi No. `type: object` means the request body is an object, and even an empty JSON object `{}` is not the same as empty request body.

Answer (score 4):

with Insomnia when use:

```
  requestBody:
    content:
      application/json: {}
```

result is this: (preview)

[image: insomnia requestbody empty json sample]

but if use this:

```
  requestBody:
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:      # Request body contents
          type: object
```

result is : (preview)

[image: openapi3 requestbody empty json object sample swagger]

Answer (score 2):

Based on Open API 3 spec, your requestBody should be like the following:

```
   requestBody:
     required: true
       description: blabla.
         content:
            application/json:
                schema:
                   type: object
                   nullable: true
```